# Python: Fastest way to find all connected labels in third dimension of an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following question. Lets assume I have a 3D array which is full of labeled objects. This means, the whole array is full of zeros, but each labeled objects are unique connected numbers in that array in a 2d slice. In my case they are just 2D labeled circles in each z level of the array, distributed in a 3d room (array). **Now I have to calculate the intersection over union between all of these labeled objects in order to find those labeled objects in z direction which IOU are above a specific threshold, to label those with the same number.**  This is because the stack is a time stack, each slice is another timepoint. The round objects could move a little bit and change size with the time (z-direction). The stack is wrong labeled, so objects which are the same through the time do not have the same label. So to make it absoulutely correctly I would have to go from timepoint to timepoint and check the IOU betwenn the objects from that timepoint to the next.I calculate the intersection over union between all labels in that array for every slice in the third dimension. **This is very slow.** In fact it would be much faster if i would just have to compare those labels which have a common index. Is there a fast numpy scipy to compare only those labels which are connected in the third dimension? Maybe there is some way to handle that proble with sets?

Here is an example picture how the labels are merged in the 3d array:

[image]

My current code looks like the following. **I have no labeled objects in this example, because in my actual case i import a already labeled image as array and i dont know how to fill a array with random labels:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((6, 2969, 3876))
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    labelnumbers = np.unique(a[i])

    #delete the zero number from labelnumbers becaus background should not be compared

    labelnumbers = np.delete(labelnumbers,0)

    labelnumbers2 = np.unique(a[i+1])
    labelnumbers2 = np.delete(labelnumbers2,0)
    for labelnumber in labelnumbers:        
        component1 = np.copy(a[i])
        component1[component1!=labelnumber] = 0
        component1[component1==labelnumber] = 1        
        component1 = component1.astype(bool)
        for labelnumber2 in labelnumbers2:
            print('component1:',labelnumber,'compoent2',labelnumber2)
            component2 = np.copy(a[i+1])
            component2[component2!=labelnumber2] = 0
            component2[component2==labelnumber2] = 1
            component2 = component2.astype(bool)
            overlap = (component1*component2).sum() # Logical AND
            if overlap>0:
                union = float((component1 + component2).sum()) # Logical OR
                IOU = overlap/union # Treats "True" as 1,
                if IOU > 0.33:
                    a[i+1][a[i+1]==labelnumber2] = labelnumber
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Are you sure there are labels in `a`? You haven't assigned any labels to this array after `a = np.zeros((6, 2969, 3876))` at all.

Comment: See my explanation. Im sorry but i dont know how to fill the array with random circle labels or label areas at all

Comment: You need to clearly define what "intersection" means in your case. For my previous answer (now removed) you were getting 0 for IOU because it is very unlikely that there is a position in any 2D slice which has the same label across all 3D slices. Are you saying that there are multiple objects across 3D that you want to collapse into one slice, and find the intersection between those multiple objects?

Comment: Yeah, hard to explain. A intersection is an overlap of two labels from different z slices. And yes the collapse of these multiple objects in one slice would be a possibility

Comment: I recommend providing an expected output **as a picture** to get a good answer.

Comment: i added a picture, hope this explain what i mean

Comment: What happens to more than 2 objects which overlap? Do you check whether they need to fulfil the IOU threshhold for the union or intersection of the other objects?

Comment: So the thing is that, the stack is a time stack, each slice is another timepoint. the round objects could move a little bit and change size with the time (z-direction). The stack is wrong labeled, so objects which are the same through the time do not have the same label. So to make it absoulutely correctly I would have to go from timepoint to timepoint and check the IOU betwenn the objects from that timepoint to the next.

Comment: Just to make sure I got your idea right, you're looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBcLa.gif) vs. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6st6Q.gif)?